# vb.NET WebAPI - Remove items from list of items being returned - pseudo cache?

Tags: vb.net

I have a straightforward vb.net WebAPI controller that returns a list of available reservations from backend SQL server (EF). This controller is middleware between a legacy scheduling system (the SQL server) and online customer reservation system. *I have read-only access to the scheduling system DB.*

The customer frontend calls the API to get available reservations to display to the customer. When a user selects a reservation data is collected and sent to employees that review it and manually key it into the scheduling system.

Perhaps you see where this is going. If the employee manual process does not happen quickly enough the next customer will still see a reservation that should be blocked resulting in a double-booking. I did anticipate this to be fringe, but is occurring enough that I need to resolve it.

The Reservation class is extremely simple, and I have a local DB within the middleware project. There is a GET controller that returns available reservations, and a POST controller that accepts the customer reservation and queues it for an employee.

```
Partial Public Class AptResult
   '// There is no PK, but start_date + begintime + resource_id assured to be unique
   Public Property start_date As String '// Example: 20230922
   Public Property begintime As String ''// Example: 0910
   Public Property resource_id As System.Guid 
   Public Property location_id As System.Guid
   Public Property duration As Integer
 End Class
```

**Proposed Solution:**

- Create a new EF object *AptBooked*, that is the same class as *AptResult*
- Modify the POST controller that accepts the customer reservation data to insert the reservation into *AptBooked*
- Modify the GET controller after returning available reservations from the scheduling system to remove any objects that exist in the *AptBooked*
- Would my LINQ query look like this?:

LINQ:

```
 Dim result = AptResult.Where(Function(p) Not AptBooked.Any(Function(p2)  p2.start_date = p.start_date and p2.begintime = p.begintime and p2.resource_id = p.resource_id and p2.location_id = p.location_id and p2.duration = p.duration))
```

**before I do this...**

- This solution seems like it will be fairly easy to implement and mostly resolve this fringe case. Is there another solution I've overlooked? This does now involve querying two separate SQL stores, converting them into comparable objects, and iterating through both sets of results.
- The scheduling system returns a limit of 100 results, with so few records performance hit should be fairly trivial?
- What, if anything is this? Pseudo cache?

Comment: I think you need to figure out how to put locks on the resources during that time frame.